# Iterate command output through delimiter in for loop in batch

Tags: batch-file

I need a method to take the command output of `FSUTIL FSINFO DRIVES` and have it list each item between spaces. For instance, if `FSUTIL FSINFO DRIVES` outputted `Drives: C:\`, I would like for this to be outputted by the for loop:

```
Drives:
C:\
```

I would also prefer if the solution didn't store the command output into a variable beforehand.

Comment: What I mean is that I would like for the for loop to directly read the command output, instead of reading a variable that contains the command output.

Comment: The only way I see this being able to output this without storing the output in a variable is to use a third party utility like `SED`.  Using a `FOR` command would store the output in a variable.

Comment: If you must, you can ignore the above rules, as long as your method doesn't use third-parties.

Comment: And can handle special characters.

Comment: There isn't any special characters in that output.  So please let us know what code you are really using that would require this type of function.

Comment: The whole special characters part isn't needed, I'd just prefer it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple nested `FOR` solution.

```
for /F "delims=" %%G IN ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do for %%H in (%%G) do echo %%H
```